# Is there an analogue of Earnshaw’s theorem for inverse cube force laws?

Tags: classical-mechanics, electrostatics, equilibrium, stability

[Earnshaw’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem) states that point charges cannot be held in electrostatic equilibrium by an electric field. Is there an analogue of this for inverse cube force laws?

Comment: Are we assuming that Laplace's Equation still holds in vacuum?

Answer (score 1):

I had a dilemma - whether to give a long or a short answer. The long one would contain a general discussion of the proof of Earnshaw's theorem and of what it becomes for a different force law. The short one gives only the results. I've decided for the latter. If you are interested in a
deeper discussion please put a specific question.

Earnshaw's theorem rests on electrostatic potential satisfying (in vacuum) Laplace's equation
$$\nabla^2 V = 0.\tag1$$
If potential of a point charge is $\propto 1/r$ then eq. (1) follows for whatever distribution of charges, in any region devoid of charge. Then it's easy to see that $V$ can have neither local maxima nor local minima, so that stable equilibrium for a test charge is ruled out.

If potential goes as $1/r^2$ (or any other power of $r$) Laplace's equation doesn't hold, but this doesn't logically imply that stable equilibrium is allowed - a more thorough discussion is required. But it's not difficult to find positive examples.

E.g. equal charges at vertices of a regular octahedron give stable equilibrium for a charge of same sign placed in the centre.

Comment: *E.g. equal charges at vertices of a regular octahedron give stable equilibrium for a charge of same sign placed in the centre.* In this example, can't the charge's potential energy be reduced by moving it perpendicular to the plane of the octahedron?

Comment: @BenCrowell What do you mean by "plane of the octahedron"?

Comment: So we need 4 dimensions for Earnshaw's theorem to hold for inverse cube laws?